# SSRS. How to change order of columns which have grouped rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have total 5 columns. `Column1`, `Column2` and `Column5` are grouped. I need to change `Column5 order`

I've added `Row Group` > `Parent Group` on `Column1` and `Row Group` > `Child Groups` on `Column2` and `Column5`

Now It looks like:

[image: how it is]

But It should be like that. How to change order of grouped column?

[image: how to group]

Comment: you wil have to add the group that is on column 5 (lets call it Group5) on column2 (lets say its group2). Otherwise column3 and column4 will only group on 'Group2' and not on 'group5'. The aggregation on column5 you can just change the Scope as needed.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but really I misunderstood your idea I need to add `Group5` on `Column2`? And how It will let me to change order of `Column5`?

Comment: Change the Sorting on Group5

Comment: How to change the Sorting of `Group5`?

Comment: On the properties of the Child Group that you defined on that column. There should be a Sorting Tab.

Comment: You misunderstand what I need. I need to move that column right as shown in my question. `Column5` now are 3rd, but It should be last one, I don't know how to move this column.

Comment: copy the formulas from column5 delete the column, add column after column4 and paste?